# Comparing char pointers to strings to insert into binary search tree

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am pretty new to c but I am working on making a binary search tree for a class project.  I need to insert char pointers to strings whether they are single words or string phrases in quotes.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to properly compare these char pointers to insert them into my tree. I've attached what I currently have for my insert function; sorry for any small errors, like I said I'm pretty new to C.  I just don't know if I'm able to use stmcpy or what would be the best method.

```
void insert(char *d)
{
    node *n = newNode(d);
    insertData(root, n);
}

void insertNode(node *a, node *b)
{
    if (a == NULL)
    {
        root = b;
        size++;
        root->freq++;
    }else if ((strcmp(b->data, a->data)) < 0)
    {
        if(a->left == NULL)
        {
            a->left = b;
            b->freq = 1;
        }else
        {
            insertData(a->left, b);
        }
    }else if ((strcmp(b->data, a->data)) > 0)
    {
        if(a->right == NULL)
        {
            a->right = b;
            b->freq = 1;
        }else
        {
            insertData(a->right,b);
        }
    }else
    {
        a->freq++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a specific question, and in response to the general question, you should use strcmp to compare strings and it looks like you're using it pretty much correctly.

Comment: `strcmp` is used correctly. Problem might be in accessing `node::data`. Better if you can show the definition of `node`.

Comment: Can you post enough of the code that we can reproduce the error on our end? Also, what specific error are you having? Single-word versus multi-word shouldn't matter here.